# How to convert optional NSData to optional Bool

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, option-type

I have a `NSData` variable called: `isMaxVersionEnabled?` it is a optional.

I want to convert `isMaxVersionEnabled` to an optional `Bool`.

So far I have figured out how to convert a `NSData` value to a bool like this:

`NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(<NSData value>)`

but I am not sure how to utilize it because the input must be unwrapped and that is a problem since `isMaxVersionEnabled` might be nil.

Comment: `guard let isMaxVersionEnabled = isMaxVersionEnabled else { return }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `NSData` Int value(very first bytes) and compare with 0 to get bool value

```
var boolValue = false
var value: Int = 0
isMaxVersionEnabled?.getBytes(&value, length: sizeof(Int))
if value != 0 {
    boolValue = true
}

print(boolValue)
```